# How can we add Header Parameters to HTTPCLIENT object

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

C# How can we add Header Parameters to HTTPCLIENT object
Post-Man Screen-Shot:

[image: A screen shot of POST-MAN which I'm capable of doing there]

I have tried the following code snippet as well but, no use.

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceBaseURL) };
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Param1", "Value1");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Param2", "Value2");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Param3", "Value3");
```

Looking forward for help. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Naresh can you please post full code snippet after the solution. I am having same requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want the regular `DefaultRequestHeaders` property and not the `Accept` property:

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Param1", "Value1");
```

You can also add the headers as part of the message (if these parameters change per request use this way instead):

```
using (var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/someendpoint"))
{
    message.Headers.Add("Param1", "Value1");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a mill for your response @maccettura

Comment: @nareshmekala if my answer worked for you please mark it as the right answer so other users know what worked.

Answer (score 1):

I thought header parameters are the root cause for an issue with my code which is not. Either the ways worked for me

```
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Param1", "Value1"); 
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Param1", "Value1");
```

Thanks Again @maccettura